How can I manage logger instances (per class) in my own libraries to allow fine-grained configuration?
I’m using Log4j for logging in a Scala project, where each class creates its logger instance using LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName.stripSuffix("$")). In another project, I extend a class from this library and use its default logger, which logs at the trace level.
In my current project, I need more granular control over the loggers. Specifically, I want to set the logging level of the library to info so that trace logs are not displayed. How can I configure the loggers to achieve this fine-grained control over logging levels?
To control logging levels, I created a specific logger in my configuration targeting the package of the extended class from the library (library.package1.package2.package3...) and set its level to info. I also have a top-level logger for my current project (thisProject.package), set to trace.
I expect no trace logs from the library will appear in the output, even though I'm extending its classes in my project. However, I'm still seeing trace logs from the library. How can I ensure the library logs only at the info level while maintaining trace logging for my project?
Here is my logger configuration(intentionally missing some configuration values, such as layout):
status = error

appenders = console

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}} %highlight{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue} %style{%12.12t}{magenta} %style{%20.20replace{%c{1.}:%L}{}{}}{cyan} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%rEx}

loggers = library-logger, project-logger

logger.project-logger.name = project.main
logger.project-logger.level = trace
logger.library-logger.name = library.project.main.myPackage
logger.library-logger.level = info

rootLogger.level = error
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

This is the class I am extending in the project from the library:
package library.project.main.myPackage

abstract class MyExtendableClass {
  protected lazy val log = com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(
    this.getClass.getName.stripSuffix("$")
  ))

  def func = {
    log.trace("This is a trace log from the library")
  }
}

And this is what I do in the current project:
package project.main.package

import library.project.main.myPackage.MyExtendableClass

class MyClazz extends MyExtendableClass {
  def myInitFunc = {
    // call func  
    func

    log.info("This is an info log after calling func")    
    // do other stuff
  }
}


In the console, I expect to see only the info log from the current project:
10-10 12:12:20.121 INFO ispatcher-27 main.package.MyClazz:30 This is an info log after calling func

But I see both log messages:
10-10 10:10:10.121 TRACE ispatcher-27 myPackage.MyExtendableClass:10 This is a trace log from the library

10-10 12:12:20.121 INFO ispatcher-27 main.package.MyClazz:30 This is an info log after calling func


You should show your actual configuration, and a snippet of log messages that you expect to be suppressed by they aren't

Thank you! I added an example logger configuration and classes to demonstrate the setup. (Since it is not my personal stuff  I added some generic code there.)

Those log entries are not printed by Log4j Core: your configuration file does not specify any layout for the STDOUT and this defaults to a Pattern Layout that only prints the log message (without neither the log level nor the logger name as in your example output). You must lack some logging API-to-logging API bridges, see Installing Log4j Core for a complete list.

BTW: Instead of passing through several logging APIs (Scala-Logging -> SLF4J -> Log4j API), you might consider using Log4j Scala API directly.

@PiotrP.Karwasz I intentionally left out some details about the configuration (like the layout) and truncated the printed log messages, because I think they are irrelevant to my problem. The log messages are displayed correctly according to the layout, etc. but the main point is that those log messages shouldn't be displayed when the logging level is set to info in the configuration file.

The layout configuration might be relevant to understand what is printed in the log files. Level filtering is based on logger names (%c), which is not the same as the class name of the caller (%C). The library.project.main.myPackage.MyExtendableClass class might very well use the project.main logger, which is configured at a TRACE level.

@PiotrP.Karwasz I have also updated the layout pattern and log messages based on the logger layout. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.
